# Tetris 2d array logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write tetris in JS with matrixes instead of sprites.
Basically to be better at visualising 2d arrays.

I rotate a block by transposing its matrix data and then reversing the rows.
But because the block's width and height doesn't completely fill this 4x4 matrix
the rotating results in the block moving, instead of rotating in place.

I can't see it, i've already spent more than two days with trying to get such a simple game as tetris working, restarting from scratch a couple of times..
I need help, i really want to be able to program games, and the only thing i got working was tic tac toe. Which i spent more time on than i should.

Here's the full js code.  Clicking the canvas rotates the piece.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 600;

// game object
var G = {};
var current = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

//GRID
G.grid = [];
G.gridColumns = 10;
G.gridRows = 15;
for (var i = 0; i < G.gridColumns; i++) {
  G.grid[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < G.gridRows; j++) {
    G.grid[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

// Array with all different blocks
G.blocks = [];
//block constructor
function block() {};
G.blocks[0] = new block();
G.blocks[0].matrix = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
];
G.blocks[0].width = 2;
G.blocks[0].height = 3;

function transpose(m) {
  // dont understand this completely, but works because j<i
  for (var i = 0; i < m.matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      var temp = m.matrix[i][j];
      m.matrix[i][j] = m.matrix[j][i];
      m.matrix[j][i] = temp;
    }
  }
}

function reverseRows(m) {
  for (var i = 0; i < m.matrix.length; i++) {
    m.matrix[i].reverse();
  }
}

function rotate(m) {
  transpose(m);
  reverseRows(m);
}

function add(m1, m2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < m1.matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m1.matrix[i].length; j++) {
      m2[i + x][j + y] = m1.matrix[i][j];
    }
  }
}

function draw(matrix) {
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (matrix[i][j] === 1) {
        ctx.fillRect(j * 20, i * 20, 19, 19);
      }
    }
  }
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, G.gridColumns * 20, G.gridRows * 20);
}


window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  rotate(G.blocks[current]);
});

function tick() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  add(G.blocks[current], G.grid);
  draw(G.grid);
}
setInterval(tick, 1000 / 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Please ignore the little quirks in my code, i learned programming by myself.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What **exactly** isn't working?

Comment: why dont use a 3x3 matrix instead of 4x4?

Comment: @Vanojx1 Some Tetrix pieces can be 4 cells long/wide probably.

Comment: @Vanojx1 Making the container the size of your biggest element made sense in my brain. I'm not the most genious of people :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are always assuming your piece is 4 tiles wide.  You may want to shrink wrap your matrix to the smallest space that is still a square.  For your Z/S blocks, it would be 3x3.  Then the **center** of your rotation would act correctly.

Your issue right now is that the rotation is kind of working correctly, but the center of your brick is at cell (2, 2) rather than (1, 1) (assuming base 0). `C` is the reference frame around which your rotation is being applied.

```
[x][ ][ ][ ][ ]      [ ][ ][X][X][ ]
[X][X][ ][ ][ ]      [ ][X][X][ ][ ]
[ ][X][C][ ][ ]  =>  [ ][ ][C][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]      [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]      [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

If you could shrink wrap your shape, you could apply your rotation and acheive the following:

```
[x][ ][ ]      [ ][X][X]
[X][C][ ]  =>  [X][C][ ]
[ ][X][ ]      [ ][ ][ ]
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice overview :)

I thought keeping all the matrixes the size of the biggest tetris piece, but that logic obviously doesn't apply here..

Do you happen to know how i would use collision in a tetris game like this, i already struggled with that too before i tried rotation.

Answer (score 7):

## Rotations

One problem with actual rotations is that some of them are not going to look all that good, even if the width of the matrix is taken into consideration. Let's see what happens with the rotation of the `I` shape:

```
. X . .        . . . .        . . X .        . . . .
. X . .   =>   X X X X   =>   . . X .   =>   . . . .
. X . .        . . . .        . . X .        X X X X
. X . .        . . . .        . . X .        . . . .
```

From a gameplay perspective, you would expect the 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> shapes to be identical to the 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> ones, respectively. But it's not what's going to happen with the generic rotation algorithm. You might address the above issue by using a non-square matrix (5x4), but the algorithm is going to get more complicated than you would have initially expected.

Actually, I'd be willing to bet that most Tetris implementations do not bother doing the rotation programmatically and simply hardcode all the different possible shapes of the tetrominoes, in a way that makes the rotations look as good and as 'fair' as possible. A nice thing about that is that you don't have to worry about their size anymore. You can just store them all as 4x4.

As we are going to see here, this can be done in a very compact format.

## Encoding tetrominoes as bitmasks

Because a tetromino is basically a set of 'big pixels' that can be either *on* or *off*, it is quite suitable and efficient to represent it as a bitmask rather than a matrix of integers.

Let's see how we can encode the two distinct rotations of the `S` shape:

```
X . . .     1 0 0 0
X X . .  =  1 1 0 0  =  1000110001000000 (in binary)  =  0x8C40 (in hexadecimal)
. X . .     0 1 0 0
. . . .     0 0 0 0

. X X .     0 1 1 0
X X . .  =  1 1 0 0  =  0110110000000000 (in binary)  =  0x6C00 (in hexadecimal)
. . . .     0 0 0 0
. . . .     0 0 0 0
```

The two other rotations are the same for this one. So, we can fully define our `S` shape with:

```
[ 0x8C40, 0x6C00, 0x8C40, 0x6C00 ]
```

Doing the same thing for each shape and each rotation, we end up with something like:

```
var shape = [
  [ 0x4640, 0x0E40, 0x4C40, 0x4E00 ], // 'T'
  [ 0x8C40, 0x6C00, 0x8C40, 0x6C00 ], // 'S'
  [ 0x4C80, 0xC600, 0x4C80, 0xC600 ], // 'Z'
  [ 0x4444, 0x0F00, 0x4444, 0x0F00 ], // 'I'
  [ 0x44C0, 0x8E00, 0xC880, 0xE200 ], // 'J'
  [ 0x88C0, 0xE800, 0xC440, 0x2E00 ], // 'L'
  [ 0xCC00, 0xCC00, 0xCC00, 0xCC00 ]  // 'O'
];
```

## Drawing them

Now, how are we going to draw a tetromino with this new format? Rather than accessing a value in a matrix with `matrix[y][x]`, we're going to test the relevant bit in our bitmask:

```
for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    if (shape[s][r] & (0x8000 >> (y * 4 + x))) {
      ctx.fillRect(x * 20, y * 20, 19, 19);
    }
  }
}
```

## Demo

Below is some demonstration code using this method.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

var shape = [
  [ 0x4640, 0x0E40, 0x4C40, 0x4E00 ], // 'T'
  [ 0x8C40, 0x6C00, 0x8C40, 0x6C00 ], // 'S'
  [ 0x4C80, 0xC600, 0x4C80, 0xC600 ], // 'Z'
  [ 0x4444, 0x0F00, 0x4444, 0x0F00 ], // 'I'
  [ 0x44C0, 0x8E00, 0xC880, 0xE200 ], // 'J'
  [ 0x88C0, 0xE800, 0xC440, 0x2E00 ], // 'L'
  [ 0xCC00, 0xCC00, 0xCC00, 0xCC00 ]  // 'O'
];

var curShape = 0, curRotation = 0;
draw(curShape, curRotation);

function draw(s, r) {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';

  for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
      if (shape[s][r] & (0x8000 >> (y * 4 + x))) {
        ctx.fillRect(x * 20, y * 20, 19, 19);
      }
    }
  }
}

function next() {
  curShape = (curShape + 1) % 7;
  draw(curShape, curRotation);
}

function rotate() {
  curRotation = (curRotation + 1) % 4;
  draw(curShape, curRotation);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<button onclick="rotate()">Rotate</button>
<button onclick="next()">Next shape</button>
```

Comment: First, Why doesn't the onclick parameter of the button tag work for me?
I have always had to use an eventlistener in my js code.

Second, could you tell me what this "(0x8000 >> (y * 4 + x))" piece of code does? I haven't even seen that operator in Javascript.

Thank you, i haven't heard of bitmasks before, and learning to use them will probably be very useful .

Comment: @onlyme0349 The operator is the "bitwise right shift operator". A good introduction to bitwise operators is [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-bitwise-operators--active-11301).

Comment: @Mark Even with that it's really hard to comprehend what's going on, especially with the iteration. Thanks though, atleast i now know what it's called. :)

Comment: @onlyme0349 Basically, we start with the most significant bit of our bitmask (0x8000 = 16th bit), we shift it 0 to 15 positions to the right (`>>`) according to x and y, and we do a bitwise AND (`&`) with the tetromino bitmask to find out whether this cell is set or not.

Comment: @Arnould I get it, thank you. One last question, about the "0x" (tag?) what is it? Is it like the "#" tag we use in css?

Comment: `0x` is the prefix used for hexadecimal notation. You can learn more about number literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates).